# Display the same column twice in self referential table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a `tableBusiness`. There are column `ID` and `BuildingID`.

`BuildingID` points to `tableBusiness` too. A building is a business.

Now I want to create rows where each row contains

`ID, BusinessTitle, BuildingTitle` defined to be the `BusinessTitle` of the business whose `ID` is the same with `BuildingID`

How would I do so?

If it's not self referential I know I can do

```
$query="Select *, Country FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC
        WHERE (".$IDWhereFinal.") AND TB.City=TC.City";
```

Here, `Country` is actually a column in table `tablecity`.

But now I want `BuildingTitle` which is not a column anywhere. It should use the field `Title` in the business whose `ID` is the same with `BuildingID`.

How would I pull that out?

I used

```
SELECT * , Country, (

SELECT Title
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TBuild
WHERE TBuild.ID = TB.Building
) AS Coba
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB, `tablecity` AS TC
WHERE TB.City = TC.City
```

Seems to work fine but kind of strange

Try another answer.

```
Select *, Country, TB.Title as BuildingTitle FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC
        WHERE TB.ID<30 AND TB.City=TC.City
```

Works fine except that column BuildingTitle is just the title of the business. I want that to be the title of the building the business is in.

Then I do

```
SELECT * , Country, Building.Title AS BuildingTitle
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB, `tablebusiness` AS Building, `tablecity` AS TC
WHERE TB.ID <30
AND TB.City = TC.City
AND TB.building = Building.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I got only businesses that are in a building

```
ID  Email   InBuildingAddress   Price   Street  Title   Website     Zip     Rating Star     Rating Weight   Latitude    Longitude   Building    City    OpeningHour     TimeStamp   ID  Email   InBuildingAddress   Price   Street  Title   Website     Zip     Rating Star     Rating Weight   Latitude    Longitude   Building    City    OpeningHour     TimeStamp   City    Country     Country     BuildingTitle
6   NULL    Unit No. 11 Lt. 6 Food Court    NULL    Jl. Arteri S. Parman    Citra   NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.168758   106.787377  200004  Jakarta     Everyday, 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200004  jakarta@swiss-belhotel.com  Lt. P-1 Unit 1 & 52-53  NULL    Jl. Letjen S. Parman No. 31     Mall Ciputra    NULL    11470   4.33333333333333    3   -6.16852955233882   106.787015629421    0   Jakarta Barat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Mall Ciputra
7   NULL    Lt. 2 No 40     NULL    Jl. K.H. Noer Ali   Eaton Bakery and Restaurant     NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.248135   106.991926  200005  Jakarta     Monday - Sunday 10:00 - 22:00   2011-11-06 22:30:37     200005  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. K.H. Noer Ali   Metropolitan Mall Bekasi    NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.248135   106.991926  0   Jakarta     NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Metropolitan Mall Bekasi
8   NULL    Lt. GF  NULL    Jl. Pluit Indah Raya    Deli Manjoo     NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.116341   106.789556  200006  Jakarta     Mon - Sun 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200006  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Pluit Indah Raya    Pluit Village Mall  NULL    14450   0   1   -6.11636729665532   106.78957198066     0   Jakarta Utara   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Pluit Village Mall
9   NULL    #18     NULL    Jl. Boulevard Palem Raya No. 38     Restaurant India    NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.22868    106.60923   200007  Jakarta     Everyday, 10:00 - 00:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200007  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Boulevard Palem Raya No. 38 lippo Karawaci 120...   Benton Junction     NULL    15811   0   0   -6.22827750567979   106.608705787526    0   Tangerang   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Benton Junction
14  NULL    Ground Floor    NULL    Jl. Raya Boulevard Kelapa Gading Blok M     Mochi-Mochi     NULL    NULL    5   1   -6.157515125    106.9084265     200009  Jakarta     Mon - Sun 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200009  communicationnetwork@sogo.co.id     Unit 159    NULL    Jl. Bulevar Kelapa Gading Blok M Kelapa Gading Per...   Mall Kelapa Gading 2    NULL    14240   1.75    4   -6.15783092569102   106.907815359612    0   Jakarta Utara   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Mall Kelapa Gading 2
16  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. HR. Rasuna Said Lt. Dasar   Rumah Makan Aroma Sulawesi  NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.2210955  106.8329755     200010  Jakarta     Everyday, 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200010  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. HR. Rasuna Said Lt. Dasar   Mall Pasar Festival     NULL    12960   1.5     2   -6.22111994514218   106.83291640369     0   Jakarta Selatan     NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Mall Pasar Festival
17  NULL    Lt. 6 Food Court 119 A  NULL    Jl. Asia Afrika Pintu 9     Alberki Khas Sulawesi   NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.228376   106.798677  200011  Jakarta     Everyday, 09:00 - 20:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200011  stc_inbox@co.id     NULL    NULL    Jl. Asia Afrika Pintu 9     STC Senayan     NULL    10270   0.5     2   -6.22839746826785   106.798676515068    0   Jakarta Pusat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   STC Senayan
20  NULL    Blok Kt Unit 34     NULL    Jl. Maleo Raya ( Bintaro Sektor 9 )     Nasi Kebuli Haji Ali    NULL    12330   0   0   -6.27829125     106.72197075    200259  Jakarta Selatan     Everyday, 16:00 - 00:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200259  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Maleo Raya ( Bintaro Sektor 9 )     Bintaro Trade Centre    NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.27829125     106.72197075    0   Tangerang Selatan   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta Selatan     Indonesia   Indonesia   Bintaro Trade Centre
21  NULL    Food Court Floor 5, No 31   NULL    Jl.Letjend Suprapto     Khas Sulawesi   NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.169621625    106.867814  200013  Jakarta     Everyday 11:00 - 18:00  2011-11-06 22:30:37     200013  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Let. Jend Suprapto Kav. 62 No. 1    Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel     NULL    10640   0   0   -6.17011293789604   106.868159676677    0   Jakarta Pusat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel
22  NULL    Food Court Floor 5, No 86   NULL    Jl.Letjend Suprapto     Kwetiau Sapi 88 Pontianak   NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.169621625    106.867814  200013  Jakarta     Everyday 10:00 - 20:00  2011-11-06 22:30:37     200013  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Let. Jend Suprapto Kav. 62 No. 1    Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel     NULL    10640   0   0   -6.17011293789604   106.868159676677    0   Jakarta Pusat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel
23  NULL    Lt. 2 Blok A 2 #19 - 21     NULL    Jl. Boulevard Artha Gading Selatan No. 1    Toreore Chicken & Joy   NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.14630575     106.89517725    200014  Jakarta     Mon - Sun 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200014  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Boulevard Artha Gading Selatan No. 1    Rukan Artha Gading Niaga    NULL    14250   2.33333333333333    3   -6.14615740918793   106.89470094061     0   Jakarta Utara   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Rukan Artha Gading Niaga
24  NULL    Food Court Floor 5, No 57   NULL    Jl.Letjend Suprapto     Ou Kie  NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.169621625    106.867814  200013  Jakarta     Everyday 11:00 - 20:00  2011-11-06 22:30:37     200013  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Let. Jend Suprapto Kav. 62 No. 1    Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel     NULL    10640   0   0   -6.17011293789604   106.868159676677    0   Jakarta Pusat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel
25  NULL    Lt. Pasar Senggol Blok Exb Unit 03  NULL    Jl. Letjen S. Parman No. 31     Bakmi Bangka    NULL    11470   0   0   -6.168758   106.787377  200004  Jakarta Barat   Everyday, 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200004  jakarta@swiss-belhotel.com  Lt. P-1 Unit 1 & 52-53  NULL    Jl. Letjen S. Parman No. 31     Mall Ciputra    NULL    11470   4.33333333333333    3   -6.16852955233882   106.787015629421    0   Jakarta Barat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta Barat   Indonesia   Indonesia   Mall Ciputra
27  NULL    Food Court Floor 5, No 98   NULL    Jl.Letjend Suprapto     Seroja Baru     NULL    NULL    0   0   -6.169621625    106.867814  200013  Jakarta     Everyday 10:00 - 19:30  2011-11-06 22:30:37     200013  NULL    NULL    NULL    Jl. Let. Jend Suprapto Kav. 62 No. 1    Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel     NULL    10640   0   0   -6.17011293789604   106.868159676677    0   Jakarta Pusat   NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta     Indonesia   Indonesia   Grand Cempaka Jakarta Hotel
28  NULL    4th Fl Unit 57  NULL    Jl. Jend. Sudirman Kav. 52 - 53 sudirman Central B...   Secret Recipe   NULL    12190   0   0   -6.226948   106.8133435     200015  Jakarta Selatan     Mon - Sun 10:00 - 22:00     2011-11-06 22:30:37     200015  NULL    Lt. Ground Unit 99  NULL    Jl. Jend. Sudirman Kav. 52 - 53 sudirman Central B...   Pacific Place Mall  NULL    12190   4.33333333333333    3   -6.22628017797778   106.812480471955    0   Jakarta Selatan     NULL    2011-11-06 22:29:28     Jakarta Selatan     Indonesia   Indonesia   Pacific Place Mall
```

Say I want all businesses whether the building is in a building or not. If the building is empty I want BuildingTitle to contain NULL. If the building is not empty, I want BuildingTitle column to contain the title of the building. How do I do so?

if a business is in a building then the column BuildingTitle should contain the name of the building. If the building is empty BuildingTitle  should be NULL

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="Select *, Country, TB.Title as BuildingTitle FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC
        WHERE (".$IDWhereFinal.") AND TB.City=TC.City";
```

And you should join tables using [Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: It's not clear. TableBusiness is used twice by the way. Once as Business and another one as Building table. So you're using it only once. Why?